# Expressing $\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} P(n) x^n$ as a rational function

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, power-series

For $x \in (-1, 1)$, the power series $f(x) = \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} P(n) x^n$, where $P(n)$ is a polynomial, converge. Within this interval of convergence, how to write $f$ as a rational function $\frac{p(x)}{q(x)}$, where $p$ and $q$ are polynomials?

Comment: Otherwise let $g_0(x)=x/(1-x),g_{k+1}(x)=xg_k'(x)$ then $f(x)=p_0+\sum_{k=0}^d p_k g_k(x)$

Answer (score 1):

Note that for $i \in \mathbb{Z}^+$, we have
$$
\frac{1}{(1 - x)^i} = \sum_{n = 0}^{\infty} \binom{n + i - 1}{n} x^{n} \, .
$$
Thus a finite linear combination of $\{ (1-x)^{-i} \}_i$ can be written as
$$
\sum_{i = 1}^{d} \frac{a_i}{(1-x)^{i}} = \sum_{n = 0}^{\infty} \sum_{i = 1}^{d} a_i \binom{n + i - 1}{n} x^{n} \, ,
$$
where $d - 1$ is the degree of $P(n)$.

As such, we only need to make the following expressions equivalent:
$$
\sum_{i = 1}^{d} a_i \binom{n + i - 1}{n} = P(n) \, .
$$
This can be done in quite a few ways, one of them being solving the following system of equations:
$$
\sum_{j=0}^{i+1} \binom{i}{j} a_{j+1} = P(-i) \, .
$$

For example, solving this with $P(n) = n^2 - 4$ gives $a_1 = -3, a_2 = -3, a_3 = 2$. I.e.,
$$
\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} (n^2 - 4)x^n = \frac{-3}{1-x} + \frac{-3}{(1-x)^2} + \frac{2}{(1-x)^3} = \frac{-3x^2 + 7x - 4}{(1-x)^3} \, .
$$